# installing SSL sha256 in iis6.0

Tags: rsa-sha256

i have to install ssl certificate with sha256 algorithm in IIS6.0.And I have my own private key generated this during the CSR request,but not able to see the private key after installing SSL in IIS 6. Could you please help

Comment: Could any one help on this since this is bit urgent for us

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://dotnetstock.com/technical/how-to-generate-a-sha256-certificate-and-how-to-install-sha256-certificate-in-iis/)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi This issue has been resovled ,I had my private key in the OPENSSL folder as  .key file. I have converted this to .pfx file using openssl commands.then reimported the certificate and private key.
Now i have my certificate with the Privatekey in the windows server2003.